# Add brackets around digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

> var string = {fld_1}-1000-{fld_1}

and I need to add {} around the digits 1000 (could be any number of digits though).

So the end string would be:

> {fld_1}-{1000}-{fld_1}

My current regex is this:

> var result = string.replace(/-(\d+)/g, '{$1}');

But I end up with this:

> {fld_1}{1000}{1000}-{fld_1}

This is for a javscript application

**Edit:**

I should have noted that the strings could be this as well:

> {fld_1}/1000-{fld_1}

or

> {fld_1}+1000/{fld_1}

Comment: I just tested it with jsfiddle and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Try: `string.replace(/-(\d+)-/g, '-{$1}-')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\d` is part of `\w` and `[_+-]` is not, you can use the word boundary assertion `\b` to your advantage:

```
'{fld_1}-1000-{fld_1}'.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g, '{$1}')
```

Note that `fld_1` is not replaced here, because `_` is part of `\w` and as such there's no transition from `\W` to `\w` or vice versa.

Comment: This is exaclty what I needed

Comment: It is a very important note, though this `'{fld-1}-1000-{fld_1}'.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g, '{$1}')` results `{fld-{1}}-{1000}-{fld_1}`

Comment: @wZVanG Yep, it's important :)